# How to use vim-easy-align to align vimscript comments?

Tags: vim, alignment

I'm trying to use [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) to align vimscript comments. For example, turn this:

```
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab' " Tab completion
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim' " File searching
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex' " LaTeX
```

to:

```
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab' " Tab completion
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'    " File searching
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'     " LaTeX
```

I'm trying vipga, then ^X (for regex), then " (double quote), and it executes but does nothing. Also tried visually selecting rows, then ga, ^X, " which also does nothing.

With [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), it's simply `:Tabular /"` but I cannot figure it out with vim-easy-align. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `:EasyAlign /"/` do something?

Comment: No, it seems. I've tried `"`, `/"/`, `/"`.

Comment: That is strange. I installed the plugin, then visually selected paragraph (`vip`), and wrote the beforementioned command (`:'<,'>EasyAlign /"/`), and it worked for me. If it is not working for you, you may consider to visit the plugin's [issue tracker](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align/issues).

Answer (score 2):

To align with easy-align inline-comments you can follow the instructions in here: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md

as the example illustrates to align inline-comments it does not matter if it is vimscript. The commands are

```
vipga-<space>
```

vip: select the whole line block

ga: easy-align mapping

-< space >: aligns inline-comments

hopefully this helps to anyone who had a hard time like me

Comment: This only aligns the last word in my inline vimscript comments.

Answer (score 2):

I believe by default, vim-easy-align will ignore strings, using the `ignore_groups` option. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> will toggle through the options for `ignore_group`. Pressing it once, the first option is to have no groups ignored.

The command to perform the alignment you desire is therefore

`gaip^G"<CR>`